# Improving speed of R function (avoiding loop)?

Tags: r, performance, loops, data.table

So I have a panel data set and would like to assign some dummy variables for changes/increases in a variable (x) from one year to another for each id. I have written a function that does exactly what I want. Unfortunately it is very slow, since the data is quite big and the function has to loop over houndred thousands of ids.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to generate these results, maybe by avoiding the looping at all.

It is worth mentioning that not all ids are observed over the full time span.

```
AddDummies <- function(ids, startYear = 2003, endYear = 2013){
  # Checks for ids over a time span if there has been an increase/change in variable x for a single id from one year to the next
  for(i in 1:length(ids)){
    cat("Progress: ", round((i/length(ids)), 4)*100, "% \n")
    for(k in startYear:endYear){
      x.curr <- fullDat[id_d == ids[i] & year == k, x] # x in year k
      x.last <- fullDat[id_d == ids[i] & year == k-1, x] # x in year k-1
      if(length(x.curr) == 0 | length(x.last) == 0){ # if id has not been in the data the year before or in the current year
        # skip and go to next iteration, since change can not be determined
        next
      } else if(x.curr != x.last){ # if there has been an change in x
        fullDat[id_d == ids[i] & year == k, changeDummy := 1] # dummy for change
        fullDat[id_d == ids[i] & year == k, changeAbsolute := (x.curr - x.last)] # absolute change
        if(x.curr > x.last){
          fullDat[id_d == ids[i] & year == k, increase := 1] # dummy for increase
        }
        if(x.curr == 1 & x.last == 0){
          fullDat[id_d == ids[i] & year == k, zeroToOne := 1] # dummy for ids with an increase in x from 0 to 1
        }
      } else {
        next
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate step by step what the function does without us deciphering the code?

Comment: You might take a look at `dplyr` and, specifically, using `group_by(id)` and then `mutate` with operations involving `ifelse`' and `lag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do each of these operations in a single line of data.table:

```
fullDat[, increase := c(F, x[-1] > x[1:(.N-1)]), by = id_d]
fullDat[, zerotoone := c(F, x[-1]==1 & x[1:(.N-1)]==0), by = id_d]
```

some data

```
library(data.table)
fullDat = data.table(
  id_d = rep(letters[1:3], each=10),
  year=rep(1:10, 3),
  x = sample(10,30,replace = T)
  )
setkey(fullDat, 'id_d', 'year')
```